# How to programmatically login on sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I want to expose a webmethod that will take in a username and password and login the user.  How would I programmatically take these parameters and sign in a user to the site, so that after the webmethod is complete, the page reloads and the user is now "logged in".  I would like to avoid using the Login asp control because I would like to send these parameters in an ajax call to the webmethod and have it log the user in that way.

Comment: Will your web service be hosted in SharePoint's context?

Comment: yes it will be hosted in sharepoint's context

Comment: How will your method be different from [`Authentication.Login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/authentication.authentication.login.aspx)?

Comment: Where are these username & password saved? Are you trying to setup something like a SSO?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used this method on a Windows Form Application and it works fine:

Note that spUsername and spPassword are the ones you have to provide in this code:

```
private bool loginSharePoint()
    {
        lbLoginStatus.Text = "Logging in Sharepoint server";

        bool isValid = false;

        //validating Sharepoint login
        string spUsername = tbSharePointUsername.Text;

        string spPassword = tbSharePointPassword.Text;


        pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, spUsername.Split('\\')[0]);

        pbLogin.PerformStep();
        // validate the credentials
        isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(spUsername.Split('\\')[1], spPassword);
        if (isValid)
        {
            pbLogin.PerformStep();

            pbLogin.PerformStep();
            site = new SPSite(tbSharePointUrl.Text);

            pbLogin.PerformStep();
            web = site.OpenWeb();

            pbLogin.PerformStep();
            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(spUsername, SPBasePermissions.Open))
                isValid = true;
            else
                isValid = false;
        }


        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you could describe a little bit more of your code.